# First derivative of scalar product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have given function $F(x)=\langle Ax,x\rangle +\langle 2b,x\rangle +c$ where $x\in R^n$, A is real, symmetric, positive definite, regular matrix in $R^{n,n}$, $b\in R^n$, $c\in R$ are fixed vectors.

I have to find $F'(x)$ and $F''(x)$.

If $F'(x)=F(h+h)-F(x)$ I got that $F(x+h)-F(x)=2\langle Ax+b,h\rangle$.
But my professor wrote that $F'(x)=2(Ax+b)$ and I don't know why that.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

$F'(x)$ is defined as the vector $[\partial F/\partial x_i]$. Take the element-wise partial derivatives and you will see the answer.